# Python Naive Bayes training issues - cannoy perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, list, numpy, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am aiming to train a Bayes model to review positive and negative sentences. I have 6000 words to train the model, and want to test it with sentences such as "I am feeling happy".

I am currently using numpy with sklearn but am having issues with a type error: "cannot perform reduce with flexible type".

I have a list of words like `words = ["good", "happy", "bad", "sad"]` and a corresponding list `wordTypes = ["positive", "positive", "negative", "negative"]`. I have tried to simplify it to just get something work so the result is the below code. I have also used "str" rather than positive and negative on `X` as well as brackets instead of square brackets.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
nv = GaussianNB()

X = [["happy","positive"], ["good","positive"], ["bad","negative"], ["poor", "negative"]]
y = ["positive","positive", "negative","negative"]
     
nv.fit(X,y)
```

I have also tried it as below, but get the following : `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['happy' 'good' 'bad' 'poor']. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

```
X = ["happy", "good", "bad", "poor"]
y = ["positive","positive", "negative","negative"]
```

Am I misunderstanding how they should be structured?

Comment: You have a bigger problem here: this model doesn’t make any sense. A Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier expects a real-valued vector for x, not a string. But yes, the model expects that X is 2-dimensional, where an individual x is a vector (possibly of length 1).

Comment: ahh right, thanks for the help. So would a standard Naive Bayes be better here? @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: You probably want to do some feature engineering, but yes. Check the documentation for what the expected input and output formats should be. (Though in some sense, what is “standard”?)